# buildout cfg requires modules that are already installed

Tags: python, version-control, buildout, egg

I am trying to run:

```
sudo bin/buildout
```

And I get a message saying:

```
mr.developer: Queued 'django-accessibillity' for checkout.
mr.developer: Queued 'django-registration' for checkout.
mr.developer: Queued 'ivc-formutils' for checkout.
```

And asks me for password for a repository. However the problem is that this repository no longer exists and I can't download files from there. Therefore I got these modules from other sources and installed them. But when I run buildout installation still asks me for  the same modules.

Is it somehow possible to get buildout to recognize that I already have these modules or is there some other workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mr.developer` will, by default, update your repositories when buildout runs. You can disable this with the `auto-checkout` option in the `[buildout]` section:

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer
# ...
auto-checkout = false
```

However, if you have a checkout that is no longer present in the repository, convert your sources to the `fs` type instead of `git` or `svn` or whatever repository type they were before.

Look for the `[sources]` section (unless a `sources` key is set in the `[buildout]` section, in which case that'll name the right section). It'll have entries like:

```
[sources]
django-accessibillity = git https://some.gitserver.com/some/repository.git
django-registration = svn https://some.svnserver.com/some/svn/repo/trunk
```

Change these to use `fs <name-of-package>` instead:

```
[sources]
django-accessibillity = fs django-accessibillity
django-registration = fs django-registration
```

Comment: mr.developer: Directory for package 'django-accessibillity' doesn't exist. Even though I can import django-accessibillity no problem.

Comment: @Marijus: since Python packages cannot actually contain `-` characters, are you certain the directory is not actually using a different name, like `django_accessibility` perhaps? The default `sources-dir` is `src`, so check your `src` subdirectory unless that key is set to something else in the `[buildout]` section.